# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1298 Unknown or incorrect time zone: 'UTC' windows

Tags: php, mysql, utc

I am getting this error while setting up a PHP source code in Windows Wamp server.

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1298 Unknown or incorrect time zone: 'UTC'

Please let me know how to solve.

Thanks.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/120945/how-do-i-resolve-this-error-error-1298-hy000-unknown-or-incorrect-time-zone

Answer (score 15):

You have three ways to solve this problem.

> **Method 1** Install the timezone database

The **mysql_tzinfo_to_sql** program loads the time zone tables in the mysql database. It is used on systems that have a zoneinfo database (the set of files describing time zones). Examples of such systems are Linux, FreeBSD, Solaris, and OS X. One likely location for these files is the /usr/share/zoneinfo directory (/usr/share/lib/zoneinfo on Solaris). If your system does not have a zoneinfo database, you can use the downloadable package described in Section 11.6, “MySQL Server Time Zone Support”.

**mysql_tzinfo_to_sql** can be invoked several ways:

```
shell> mysql_tzinfo_to_sql tz_dir
shell> mysql_tzinfo_to_sql tz_file tz_name
shell> mysql_tzinfo_to_sql --leap tz_file
```

For the first invocation syntax, pass the zoneinfo directory path name to **mysql_tzinfo_to_sql** and send the output into the **mysql** program. For example:

```
shell> mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root mysql
```

**mysql_tzinfo_to_sql** reads your system's time zone files and generates SQL statements from them. **mysql** processes those statements to load the time zone tables.

The second syntax causes **mysql_tzinfo_to_sql** to load a single time zone file *tz_file* that corresponds to a time zone name tz_name:

```
shell> mysql_tzinfo_to_sql tz_file tz_name | mysql -u root mysql
```

If your time zone needs to account for leap seconds, invoke **mysql_tzinfo_to_sql** using the third syntax, which initializes the leap second information. *tz_file* is the name of your time zone file:

```
shell> mysql_tzinfo_to_sql --leap tz_file | mysql -u root mysql
```

After running **mysql_tzinfo_to_sql**, it is best to restart the server so that it does not continue to use any previously cached time zone data.

source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-tzinfo-to-sql.html

> **Method 2** Update your my.cnf file to use a timezone offset instead

```
default-time-zone = +0:00
```

> **Method 3** Remove or comment out offending statement from your my.cnf file

```
# default-time-zone = UTC
```

This will cause it to inherit the timezone from the OS instead.

Comment: on macOS using MAMP this works:
sudo /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /private/var/db/timezone/tz/2020d.1.0/zoneinfo | /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql -uroot -proot mysql

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. it seems your time zone table from mysql is empty. to resolve this , follow the instructions below:

1. Stop mysql server (if running)
2. Download timezone list from: [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/timezones.html)
3. Extract the file.
4. if your're using xampp/wamp server , go to c drive> xamp/wamp> mysql> data> mysql
   and paste the extracted files here. (replace the files if necessary).

   *(N.B: if you're not using xampp/wamp servers, you can also follow the same
   procedure to replace the files.)*
5. Finally , start mysql server again and check phpmyadmin>mysql>`time_zone_name`
   table.
   [Hope that will resolve your problem]

---