# Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value - Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, datetime, laravel-5

I did a fresh install of Laravel 5.4 using the official Laravel installer for Composer. I ran `php artisan make:auth` to create the system for login/register. The login page works when I manually enter in the user in the database, but my register page gives me the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '2017-03-12 02:53:06' for column 'updated_at' at row 1
```

and

```
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '2017-03-12 02:53:06' for column 'updated_at' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Jonathan Stowe, john@doe.com, $2y$10$ukSU8/YktI88igoHxhgjdeahZhFZinoR.8vCNMpjv9CjeQRe.izsq, 2017-03-12 02:53:06, 2017-03-12 02:53:06))
```

Im using PHP v7.1.1, MySQL v5.6.35, Larval 5.4.*

Googling the error only showed info for custom made migrations, but not the default ones. Did I configure something wrong? Or is this a known error? I can supply any files needed.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: how are you populating the values?

Comment: Check your field datatype it should be datetime instead of only date

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That time doesn't actually exist :) I'm assuming that you're timezone using something that is DST.

Between 2017-03-12 02:00:00 and 2017-03-12 02:59:59 that time just simply doesn't exist that's why you're getting that error.

Comment: So how would I fix that? I haven't modified any of the files.

Comment: Your MySQL server is probably on a DST timezone, and you're storing data likely in UTC which doesn't have DST. You would have to change your timezone on the SQL server to use UTC, but that comes with it's own challenges now with existing data.

Comment: I've explained how to do that here in this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42589490/sqlstatehy000-general-error-1298-unknown-or-incorrect-time-zone-utc-windo/42589586#42589586

Comment: Make sure the timezone on the server and MySQL is the same. If MySQL is not on the correct timezone you can update it with `SET GLOBAL time_zone = timezone;`

Comment: @Gab that will only work until the server is restarted, after that it'll revert back to whatever it was before.

Comment: @Augwa neither of those methods have worked for me. I am using MAMP v4 and the MySQL server won't start when I create a my.cnf file

Comment: Well your problem will go away seemingly 12 minutes for another year at least. What's the error in your mysql-error.log ?

Comment: @Augwa I found it. It took me a bit, but I just change the TimeZone to `default-time-zone = "-05:00"` which let the server start.

Comment: that'll cause you some problems FYI, you're better to do "00:00" doing "-05:00" means that you're always GMT-5, so today you're GMT-5 and tomorrow you're actually GMT-4 even though your server says you're still GMT-5. This will be super important if you ever decide to use the `CONVERT_TZ` function.