# How to set a non working timezone in Cake

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Hi so I'm trying to change the timezone in my project but, it doesn't seem to be working.

I've tried this code and left the timezone => 'UTC' in the app.php:

```
date_default_timezone_set(Configure::read('Europe/Paris'));
```

And having this error:

Notice: date_default_timezone_set(): Timezone ID '' is invalid in....

EDIT 1:

app.php:

```
'App' => [
    'namespace' => 'App',
    'encoding' => env('APP_ENCODING', 'UTF-8'),
    'defaultLocale' => env('APP_DEFAULT_LOCALE', 'en_US'),
    'defaultTimezone' => env('APP_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE', 'Europe/Paris'),
```

bootstrap.php:

```
date_default_timezone_set(Configure::read('App.defaultTimezone'));
```

Comment: This would suggest that `Configure::read('Europe/Dublin')` is returning an empty string. I imagine you want something more like `Configure::read('timezone')` instead.

Comment: @AlexHowansky but I need to change the time since by default is wrong in my chase..

Comment: `Configure::read($key)` presumably returns the configuration value associated with the key `$key`. Your config file doesn't have a key named `Europe/Dublin`. You need to either use the correct key and set its value to `Europe/Dublin`, or hardcode `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Dublin')`. The former would be preferred.

Comment: I.e., why would you leave `timezone => 'UTC'` in the config and then try to change it to something else later? Just change it to `timezone => 'Europe/Dublin'`.

Comment: @AlexHowansky because when declaring timezone => 'Europe/Paris' it's giving me an error: General error: 1298 Unknown or incorrect time zone: 'Europe/Paris''

Comment: That error is coming from your database, not from PHP. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42589490/sqlstatehy000-general-error-1298-unknown-or-incorrect-time-zone-utc-windo).

Comment: @AlexHowansky in the database (phpmyadmin) the time is in the correct format..

Comment: If you run `SET time_zone = 'Europe/Paris';` in phpmyadmin, does it work?

Comment: @GregSchmidt Nope, it results in Unknown or incorrect time zone. In phpmyadmin the timezone is good, the only problem is with the Cake

Comment: If that statement fails when run in phpmyadmin, then the problem is not with Cake, but with your MySQL installation. Check [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-tzinfo-to-sql.html).

Answer (score 1):

Got to **config/app.php** and edit /change **defaultTimezone**:

```
'App' => [
    'namespace' => 'App',
    'encoding' => env('APP_ENCODING', 'UTF-8'),
    'defaultLocale' => env('APP_DEFAULT_LOCALE', 'en_US'),
    'defaultTimezone' => env('APP_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE', 'Europe/Berlin'), // <---- set your
```

and **config/bootstrap.php**

```
date_default_timezone_set(Configure::read('App.defaultTimezone'));
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me, still with the same error: General error: 1298 Unknown or incorrect time zone: 'Europe/Paris'

Comment: postin in question   part of your app.php like mine, also date_default_timezone_set

Comment: Server, php version ??

Comment: >> I've tried this code and left the ```timezone => 'UTC' ```in the app.php:  ????

Comment: No, I changed everything but as I said it gave me that error. I'm using CakePHP 3.8 with phpmyadmin